# How to filter a flux for all elements having the highest value

Tags: spring, project-reactor

How do I filter a publisher for the elements having the highest value without knowing the highest value beforehand?

Here is a little test to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
@Test
fun filterForHighestValuesTest() {
    val numbers = Flux.just(1, 5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 8, 4, 3)
        // what operators to apply to numbers to make the test pass?

    StepVerifier.create(numbers)
        .expectNext(8)
        .expectNext(8)
        .verifyComplete()
}
```

Ive started with the reduce operator:

```
@Test
fun filterForHighestValuesTestWithReduce() {

    val numbers = Flux.just(1, 5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 8, 4, 3)
        .reduce { a: Int, b: Int -> if( a > b) a else b }

    StepVerifier.create(numbers)
        .expectNext(8)
        .verifyComplete()
}
```

and of course that test passes but that will only emit a single `Mono` whereas I would like to obtain a `Flux` containing all the elements having the highest values e.g. 8 and 8 in this simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll need state for this so you need to be careful to have **per-Subscription state**. One way of ensuring that while combining operators is to use `compose`.

## Proposed solution

```
Flux<Integer> allMatchingHighest = numbers.compose(f -> {
        AtomicInteger highestSoFarState = new AtomicInteger(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        AtomicInteger windowState = new AtomicInteger(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

        return f.filter(v -> {
            int highestSoFar = highestSoFarState.get();
            if (v > highestSoFar) {
                highestSoFarState.set(v);
                return true;
            }
            if (v == highestSoFar) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        })
                .bufferUntil(i -> i != windowState.getAndSet(i), true)
                .log()
                .takeLast(1)
                .flatMapIterable(Function.identity());
    });
```

Note the whole `compose` lamdba can be extracted into a method, making the code use a method reference and be more readable.

#### Explaination

The solution is done in 4 steps, with the two first each having their own `AtomicInteger` state:

1. Incrementally find the new "highest" element (so far) and `filter` out elements that are smaller. This results in a `Flux<Integer>` of (monotically) increasing numbers, like `1  5  7 8 8`.
2. `buffer` by chunks of equal number. We use `bufferUntil` instead of `window*` or `groupBy` because the most degenerative case were numbers are all different and already sorted would fail with these
3. skip all buffers but one (`takeLast(1)`)
4. "replay" that last buffer, which represents the number of occurrences of our highest value (`flatMapIterable`)

This correctly pass your `StepVerifier` test by emitting `8 8`. Note the intermediate buffers emitted are:

```
onNext([1])
onNext([5])
onNext([7, 7, 7])
onNext([8, 8])
```

#### More advanced testing, justifying `bufferUntil`

A far more complex source that would fail with `groupBy` but not this solution:

```
Random rng = new Random();
//generate 258 numbers, each randomly repeated 1 to 10 times
//also, shuffle the whole thing
Flux<Integer> numbers = Flux
        .range(1, 258)
        .flatMap(i -> Mono.just(i).repeat(rng.nextInt(10)))
        .collectList()
        .map(l -> {
            Collections.shuffle(l);
            System.out.println(l);
            return l;
        })
        .flatMapIterable(Function.identity())
        .hide();
```

This is one example of what sequence of buffers it could filter into (keep in mind only the last one gets replayed):

```
onNext([192])
onNext([245])
onNext([250])
onNext([256, 256])
onNext([257])
onNext([258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258])
onComplete()
```

Note: If you remove the `map` that shuffles, then you obtain the "degenerative case" where even `windowUntil` wouldn't work (the `takeLast` would result in too many open yet unconsumed windows).

This was a fun one to come up with!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to map the flux of ints to a flux of lists with one int in each, reduce the result, and end with flatMapMany, i.e.

```
final Flux<Integer> numbers = Flux.just(1, 5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 8, 4, 3);
final Flux<Integer> maxValues =
    numbers
        .map(
            n -> {
              List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
              list.add(n);
              return list;
            })
        .reduce(
            (l1, l2) -> {
              if (l1.get(0).compareTo(l2.get(0)) > 0) {
                return l1;
              } else if (l1.get(0).equals(l2.get(0))) {
                l1.addAll(l2);
                return l1;
              } else {
                return l2;
              }
            })
        .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution that worked for me -

```
    Flux<Integer> flux =
            Flux.just(1, 5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 8, 4, 3).collectSortedList(Comparator.reverseOrder()).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
    StepVerifier.create(flux).expectNext(8).expectNext(8).expectNext(7).expectNext(5);
```

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is to group the `Flux` prior to the reduction and flatmap the GroupedFlux afterwards like this:

```
@Test
fun filterForHighestValuesTest() {
    val numbers = Flux.just(1, 5, 7, 2, 8, 3, 8, 4, 3)
        .groupBy { it }
        .reduce { t: GroupedFlux<Int, Int>, u: GroupedFlux<Int, Int> ->
            if (t.key()!! > u.key()!!) t else u
        }
        .flatMapMany {
            it
        }

    StepVerifier.create(numbers)
        .expectNext(8)
        .expectNext(8)
        .verifyComplete()
}
```

Comment: I'd still be interested if there is a better approach.

Comment: groupBy has a big limitation in that if it creates a lot of groups and some don't get consume, if will lock